# Is Ubuntu Training Available?

Tags: boot

Are there any courses on Ubuntu for beginners? I would like to replace Windows 7, but see that a few users are having trouble booting Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

No there won't be any problem if you install the Ubuntu in a correct way. You can get the required training here [Training](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Training)
Follow the steps described here to install Ubuntu [Install Ubuntu](http://hub4pc.blogspot.in/2013/09/dual-booting-ubuntu-along-with-windows7.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.